# how to maintain the same socket connection on browser refresh?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I want to maintain the same socket connection on browser refresh . I understand that each time a page is reloaded a new socket connection is made , but is there any way to maintain the old socket connection on browser refresh? I want to achieve this in my game because on browser refresh the game will be discarded and a new game will start because the game identifies a new socket connection as  a new player.

Comment: You seem to have your terms mixed up. What you "seem" to be looking for is something like "sessions", in which you would maintain a cookie or token on the client to be sent in establishing requests. i.e, "send the same token to resume the session". You could therefore likely be more explicit about what you need to happen.

Comment: Instead you can keep user ID with socket. On new connection set user ID to socket. And use that as condition to discard or not.

Comment: @NeilLunn , I don't think that's the solution to this problem coz sessions help us in to stay logged in to the page and not during sockets connection that on disconnect it will maintain the same old socket connection. A particular user can have multiple socket connections, so sessions help us i identifying the user not the socket i suppose

Comment: @RahulPatil no that's not the solution i suppose